# get link after href-Tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, xml, beautifulsoup

i want to download all the pictures from this side in high resolution and not the preview pictures:

https://www.booklooker.de/B%C3%BCcher/Donna-W-Cross+Die-P%C3%A4pstin/id/A02A8f9001ZZl

The link -> https://xxxxx.de to the images i want to download is stored in this part of the html-code:
[link to the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flrEN.png)

The Code i tried so far was that:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get("https://www.booklooker.de/B%C3%BCcher/Donna-W-Cross+Die-P%C3%A4pstin/id/A02A8f9001ZZl")

souped = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
for pic in souped.find_all(class_="preview hasXXL"):   
   print(pic['href'])
```

With that i get to the right part of the code. But i don't get it how to scrape the link after the href-tag. When i want to scarpe it i get that results:

```
/app/detail.php?id=A02A8f9001ZZl&amp;picNo=1" id="preview_1
```

But i expect that:

```
https://images.booklooker.de/x/02Sh07/Donna-W-Cross+Die-P%C3%A4pstin.jpg
```

What did i do wrong?

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the image URLs (e.g. `https://images.booklooker.de/t/02Sh07/Donna-W-Cross+Die-P%C3%A4pstin.jpg`) then you'd need to follow the *previewImage* elements in the HTML (not the "preview hasXXL" class) and extract the "src" attribute from the img element for the URL.

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.booklooker.de/B%C3%BCcher/Donna-W-Cross+Die-P%C3%A4pstin/id/A02A8f9001ZZl"
page = requests.get(url)

souped = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

for pic in souped.find_all("img", class_="previewImage"):   
    src = pic['src']

    # Next change thumbnail URL to full res image
    src = src.replace("/t/", "/s/")

    print(src)
```

**Output:**

```
https://images.booklooker.de/s/02Sh07/Donna-W-Cross+Die-P%C3%A4pstin.jpg
...
https://images.booklooker.de/s/02Sh0S/Donna-W-Cross+Die-P%C3%A4pstin.jpg
```

Comment: The output is : ```https://www.booklooker.de/app/detail.php?id=A02A8f9001ZZl&picNo=1
https://www.booklooker.de/app/detail.php?id=A02A8f9001ZZl&picNo=2
https://www.booklooker.de/app/detail.php?id=A02A8f9001ZZl&picNo=3
https://www.booklooker.de/app/detail.php?id=A02A8f9001ZZl&picNo=4
https://www.booklooker.de/app/detail.php?id=A02A8f9001ZZl&picNo=5
https://www.booklooker.de/app/detail.php?id=A02A8f9001ZZl&picNo=6
https://www.booklooker.de/app/detail.php?id=A02A8f9001ZZl&picNo=7```
I copy pasted your code

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast answer! That totally makes sense. 

But if i run your code, i get to the link to the 'detail' page and not the link with that i could download the images. 

That means if i paste the link to my browser, i get for example to this page: 
 [link](https://www.booklooker.de/app/detail.php?id=A02A8f9001ZZl&picNo=3)

But is is possible to extract the link in that way that we get to this page?
 [link](https://images.booklooker.de/x/02Sh07/Donna-W-Cross+Die-P%C3%A4pstin.jpg)

Comment: That link is in a separate img element with id="currentImage"and class="articleImage".

Comment: Thanks a lot! But with that code i download the 'previewImage'. If possible, i want to download the picture in high resolution. That means the link in the `class_='preview hasXXL'` - tag. Is that possible?

Comment: Not sure if works in ever case but if change the path from https://images.booklooker.de/t/ to https://images.booklooker.de/s/ then get the URL to full res image. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to download images, you may search for the `<img>` tag and utilise it's `src` attribute which provides the accurate information.

#### Your Modified Code:

**Method 1: Searching for `<img>` with `class="prevewImage"` after reviewing the html code.**

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://www.booklooker.de/B%C3%BCcher/Donna-W-Cross+Die-P%C3%A4pstin/id/A02A8f9001ZZl")

souped = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
for pic in souped.find_all("img", class_="previewImage"): # <img src>
    print(pic["src"])
```

**Method: Using the `.img` to find the image tag that is associated with the searching `<a>`.**

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://www.booklooker.de/B%C3%BCcher/Donna-W-Cross+Die-P%C3%A4pstin/id/A02A8f9001ZZl")

souped = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
for pic in souped.find_all(class_="preview hasXXL"): # <a> <img src> </a>
    print(pic.img["src"])
```

##### Output:

```
https://images.booklooker.de/t/02Sh07/Donna-W-Cross+Die-P%C3%A4pstin.jpg
https://images.booklooker.de/t/02Sh08/Donna-W-Cross+Die-P%C3%A4pstin.jpg
...
https://images.booklooker.de/t/02Sh0S/Donna-W-Cross+Die-P%C3%A4pstin.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But with that code i download the 'previewImage'. If possible, i want to download the picture in high resolution. That means the link in the `class_='preview hasXXL'` - tag. Is that possible?

Comment: @BenediktFaude, looking carefully, the <a> tag points to the exact same url as the <img src>

Comment: @BenediktFaude, if you would like to use the class `'preview hasXXL'` to search for the <a>, you may use the code:
```py
for pic in souped.find_all(class_="preview hasXXL"):
    print(pic.img["src"])
``` 
[Code Updated in post]
You can use that method as well to find the high resolution images.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the max res images from there:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.booklooker.de/B%C3%BCcher/Donna-W-Cross+Die-P%C3%A4pstin/id/A02A8f9001ZZl'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
data_obj = json.loads(soup.select_one('div#imageWrapper').get('data-imageinfo'))['images']
for x in data_obj:
    print(data_obj[x]['url_xxl'])
```

Result:

```
https://images.booklooker.de/x/02Sh07/Donna-W-Cross+Die-P%C3%A4pstin.jpg
https://images.booklooker.de/x/02Sh08/Donna-W-Cross+Die-P%C3%A4pstin.jpg
https://images.booklooker.de/x/02Sh09/Donna-W-Cross+Die-P%C3%A4pstin.jpg
https://images.booklooker.de/x/02Sh0C/Donna-W-Cross+Die-P%C3%A4pstin.jpg
https://images.booklooker.de/x/02Sh0F/Donna-W-Cross+Die-P%C3%A4pstin.jpg
https://images.booklooker.de/x/02Sh0M/Donna-W-Cross+Die-P%C3%A4pstin.jpg
https://images.booklooker.de/x/02Sh0S/Donna-W-Cross+Die-P%C3%A4pstin.jpg
```